# Getting error: "TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()." when running Django Server

Tags: python, django, url, view

Every time I try to run my backend server with Django I get the error "TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()."

Here is a full traceback:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10e662578>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/dev/recipe_organizer/backend/recipe_organizer/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
  File "/Users/lyndseearmstrong/.virtualenvs/recipe_organizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from views import RecipeList, RecipeDetail, AddRecipe


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RecipeList.as_view(), name='recipe-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RecipeDetail.as_view(), name='recipe-detail'),
    url(r'^add-recipe/$', AddRecipe.as_view(), name='add-recipe'),
]
```

And here are my views:

```
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

from serializers import RecipeSerializer
from models import Recipe
from rest_framework.response import Response


class RecipeList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()


class RecipeDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()


class AddRecipe(CreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['thumbnail'] = request.data['photo']
        serializer = RecipeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This all started happening when I upgraded my computer to El Capitan. Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that you are now using the newest version of django. django 1.9 deprecated some url stuff: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't included it in your question, but the traceback shows that you are still using a string instead of a callable for this URL pattern:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

You can prevent the error by importing the `serve` view:

```
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

An alternative approach, [as recommended by the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development), is to use `static`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```